# How to convert 'open web site from folder' to csproj based 'ASP.NET Web Application' project

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

The title pretty much says it all, I've got a 'web site' that was built and checked into vss and to open it we are going to file > open > web site, and picking the folder.  This is the technique that gets you a project but without a cs/vb proj file.

Is there any easy way to convert this to an 'ASP.NET Web Application' project, complete with csproj (or vbproj)?

Also, this is in VS2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good [write up](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx) on it from Scott Guthrie:

The biggest problem that you'll run into is if you use the membership profile class.  It's autogenerated for you with a web site project, but you'll have to generate your own with a web application project.  Scott's guide will help you through that.

Good luck!!

[EDIT] - I should mention that I had to do the same thing (convert a C# web site to a C# web project) and used Scott's steps to do this.  Everything was very simple except for the Profile road bump...but even that wasn't bad at all.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks man, my google fu was weak on this one

Comment: Great!  I think that link came up lower on the first page of google when I originally found it, but it's from ScottGu, so it had to be good.  :)  Hope it works out for you.