# Visual Studio 2013 Keeps Crashing with Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I have integrated Typescript + Web Essentials into my project, on which I've worked with VS 2012 so far.

I had a problem with typescript that did not compile on save and I edited my csproj according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867390/using-typescript-in-an-existing-visual-studio-web-site-project), which solved my problem.

The other day I installed VS2013, installed Web Essentials 2013 and since then everytime I load my solution VS2013 crashes.
  If I uninstall Web Essentials, everything works fine.

I tried removing the text I had edited into the csproj but to no avail.

This is the problem's details I get from the crash:

```
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.30110.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52cfb65a
  Problem Signature 04: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor
  Problem Signature 05: 12.0.21005.1
  Problem Signature 06: 524fcbc8
  Problem Signature 07: 2e6
  Problem Signature 08: 19
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Not much idea as to how to fix this issue.

**EDIT:** I've noticed the crash happens only when I open a .ts file. The solution kept insta-crashing since there were .ts files opened already. I disabled Web Essentials, closed them all, enabled WE and then the solution opened without the crash. Then opening a .ts file triggered the crash.

Here is the stack trace:

```
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VSEditor.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Implementation.ContentTypeRegistryImpl.GetContentType(string typeName)    Unknown
    WebEssentials2013.dll!MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Margin.TextViewMargin.CreateTextViewHost(string contentType)  Unknown
    WebEssentials2013.dll!MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Margin.TextViewMargin.CreatePreviewControl(double width)  Unknown
    WebEssentials2013.dll!MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.MarginBase.CreateMarginControls() Unknown
    WebEssentials2013.dll!MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.CompilingMarginBase.CreateMarginControls()    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown

mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't going to be enough info to track down the bug.  It's a NRE but without the stack trace can't see where it is coming from.  Can you attach a debugger and get a full trace?  I know @slaks would be happy to fix it once a trace was available

Comment: @JaredPar Thanks, I edited my question with the stack trace and some extra bit of information I found. Hope it will be useful. Let me know if there's anything else I can pull that will be of help.

Comment: This was already fixed in WE nightlies (which require VS Update 2 CTP 2).  https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/776 https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/786 https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/759 https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/752

Comment: Attach debugger, catch exception, look at the locals (if possible).

Comment: @SLaks Good to hear, I'll try that next week! Thank you

Comment: @OmriAharon how to uninstall  webessentials. It's like a hell of  mess for me.

Comment: @Robert_Junior You can uninstall it from the package manager (you can right click on your project/solution and then `manage nuget packages...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any seekers - install VS 2013 Update 2 and it will not crash anymore.

Comment: I thought that's what you meant, sorry. I have updated to update 2. I uninstalled and reinstalled, it's a little bit quicker but still a lot slower than I'd expect.

Comment: @DeeMac Edited my answer, I agree I wasn't clear about which update to perform. Does it still crash though?

Comment: Sadly, even using VS 2013 Update 5, with Web Essentials 2013, if you ever move any of the bundle xml files, or Odin forbid, delete one, you complete wreck Web Essentials ability to bundle/minify. You can still see the context click menu, but it does nothing and the top menu option is gone. Seems like this might be a useful dev tool, but... :-(