# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web with Update 2 RC - got no Typescript installaaion

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-express, failed-installation

Sorry,

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
12.0.30324.00 Update 2 RC
doesn't offer TypeScript to me.
(have installed 2 RC)

Anny suggestioms?

I thoroughly have looked for other answers, telling us to look for each item while creating a new web / adding a new item to the project.

Please tell as well, me if anyone has the same problem. Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case the .ts icon is correct, but the compiler isn't automatically generating a .js file. I've already tried a few other suggestions from other forums/topics, but so far no luck.

Comment: Didn't see anything obvious in Process Monitor. Adding an Import line to the Web Project didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no template for it for some reason, but if you just add a new file to your project, and use the `.ts` extension, the TypeScript compiler should work when you save the file.

In Update 2 RC, Visual Studio doesn't show the file as being nested anymore either. It's just a `"TS"` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kindly for the quick answer.

Yes, while missing selection-menu-items for TS, I can do some TS this way:
first add a new file as Javascript-file, then put in some code and then rename it to TS. If i do this in a ASP.Net-project and not in a website-project, it will be displayed with the right TS-Logo as favicon (ico). But then it will be treated as a Javascript file, e.g. without extended typescript-expressions like 'function function1(user: string)' instead of 'function function1(user)' - without type setting.

So if I want to execute a project with some HTML-file as starting point that is calling a function of this TS-file, I must first manually compile the TS-file to a javascript file (console with tsc.exe ), replacing in my project the TS-file by the resulting JS-file etc. ...

Juno

Answer (score 0):

There a few suggestions like this:
[Using TypeScript in an existing Visual Studio Web Site project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867390/using-typescript-in-an-existing-visual-studio-web-site-project)

This will get it compiling, but not necessarily get the intellisense/syntax highlighting working.

(I'm still working on that)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with final (RTM) versions - I installed `Express for Windows Update 2` and then `Express for Web` and TypeScript didn't work. Repairing `Update 2` didn't help.

So I uninstalled both (Express for Windows and for Web), then I installed only `Express for Web` and then `Update 2` and it worked. Finally I installed `Express for Windows Update 2`.

I am using *New Project* dialog, there is *HTML Application with TypeScript* template. I don't see any TypeScript template in *New Web Site* dialog.